# How to display names under same card when using RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Before explaining the problem I'm facing, I have to admit that my UI skills are not so great. So the solution could be much easier than I think. That being said, lets start. I have created a layout using RecyclerView that has the following behavior:

```
[Avatar] [Username]
```

For example:

```
[Avatar] Avi Benson
[Avatar] Ben Dixson
[Avatar] Noris Danilov
[Avatar] Sofi Dan
[Avatar] Neli Maximov
```

I want to create the following layout:

```
[Letter] 
[Avatar] [Username]
[Avatar] [Username]
```

Where `[Letter]` is the first letter of the last name. I use cards to display each item but I want the cards that have same letter to be in the same card. Meaning I will have one card for each letter but when user is pressing the card, it will select only the selected user card (and not the full letter card). For example:

```
B 
[Avatar] Avi Benson
D 
[Avatar] Ben Dixson
---------------------
[Avatar] Noris Danilov
---------------------
[Avatar] Sofi Dan
M 
[Avatar] Neli Maximov
```

Basically, I want to get the same layout as I have in my contacts app:

[image]

Currently, the layout of each item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/avatar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The Java code:

```
rvContacts = (RecyclerView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.contacts);

Query userQuery = connectedGroupDocumentRef.collection("contacts").orderBy("fullname", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
FirestoreRecyclerOptions<User> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>().setQuery(userQuery, User.class).build();
adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<User, UserViewHolder>(options) {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_item, parent, false);
        return new UserViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull User model) {
        // Set avatar
        // Code

        // Set full name
        holder.textFullName.setText(model.getFullname());
    }
};

rvContacts.setHasFixedSize(true);
rvContacts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
rvContacts.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Note that I use firebase to fetch data. The `User` class contains one field `fullname` and one getter/setter for it.

The first thing that I understand we should do is to add another `TextView` in the layout. But what should I do then? How can I know that there is already a letter? Also, How can I keep the cards under the same layout? Is each name is a card or we have a card for each letter (and not for each name)? If it has a card only for each letter, then how can I press a specific username (for example for editing it's info)?

Answer (score -1):

Try nested recyclerview, means two recyclerviews.
1 parent, 2nd child recyclerview.
make 1st recyclerview's layout and add a recyclerview in it then make a layout for child recyclerview too.

Comment: It feels like complicating things no? I'm sure it's possible with one recyclerview.